# Is it possible to retrieve EKS ClusterConfig yaml file used to create eks cluster with eksctl

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

So if the cluster was created with  the following command

```sh
eksctl create cluster  -f config/prod.yaml
```

**prod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
....
```

How to obtain a current version of the prod.yaml if that file was lost (not accessible anymore)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ClusterConfig` is not stored inside the cluster currently. So if you lose it you can not get it back from the cluster. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/642) to support storing that as a configMap.

Having said that you should probably store it in a version control system to avoid losing it even if the feature to store the ClusterConfig as a ConfigMap is implemented sometime in future.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - I just inherited the cluster and it seems that the production config is way off with what the real cluster is.

Comment: @DmitrySemenov did you find a way to recover the config file? what if the cluster was created via the AWS EKS UI?

Comment: Not possible @CesarFlores